# Formatting NSString from indexpath.row in an Array to currency format

Tags: iphone

Hi I'm trying to convert a string from indexPath.row in an array in currency format. Below is my code. But when i run on the phone, nothing appears in the lbl - it's blank. Help is appreciated! Thanks!!

```
            NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        NSString *groupingSeparator = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
        [formatter setGroupingSeparator:groupingSeparator];
        [formatter setGroupingSize:3];
        [formatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:NO];
        [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0]; //No decimal showings - to show 2 decimal digits enter 2 instead of 0
        [formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];

        totalnoformat = [[NSNumber alloc]init];
        totalSCformat = [[NSString alloc]init];

        totalnoformat = [total objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        totalSCformat = [formatter stringFromNumber:totalnoformat];

        cell.amountlbl.text = totalSCformat;
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about what is "total"?

Comment: Total is the array from which i need a string formatted

Comment: And, are you sure that the elements are objects from NSNumber class?

Comment: Yes the objects in the array are from NSNumbers.

Comment: Can you Edit adding the full code for filling the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several issues that you might want to clean up. Here are some suggestions.

1. Your number formatter should not be initialized inside
   `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` since it will create one every time a new
   cell in initialized or dequeued. Make the formatter a property of
   your view controller and initialize it once in `viewDidLoad`.
2. Your calls to alloc/init:

   ```
   totalnoformat = [[NSNumber alloc]init];
   totalSCformat = [[NSString alloc]init];
   ```

   are unnecessary. You should remove those.
3. You should make sure that your `total` array has been initialized properly and that the values are actually getting added to it. Set a break point at this line:

   ```
   totalnoformat = [total objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   ```

   When it breaks, hover your mouse pointer over the `total` variable
   and see what the debugger says its memory address is. If it's
   0x0000, then it's nil and hasn't been initialized. That same
   technique of mousing over the variable will also tell you how many
   items are in array.
4. It appears you've created a custom cell. You have a couple potential
   issues with doing that. You need to make sure that your custom cell
   has its class is set to your custom cell class name. You also have
   to make sure you've connected your `amountlbl` property to an
   outlet, otherwise setting its text will do nothing.
5. If nothing else works, maybe there's an issue with your number
   formatter. Comment out all of your formatter properties you've set
   and try something minimal like this:

   ```
   NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
   ```

   and then try to set your cell text with a static number like this:

   ```
   cell.amountlbl.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:
                                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.75]];
   ```